# "No such table exists"

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

The error is:

> Query failed to execute: no such table: L.ID1

I am using the following database https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/socialdata.html and the table in question clearly exists. What is the reason why I'm receiving this error? Here is my query:

```
select H.name,H.grade
from Highschooler H, Likes L
where H.ID not in L.ID1 and H.ID not in L.ID2
order by H.grade,H.name
;
```

Comment: Run `.schema` on the db

Comment: I believe you may want to use a subquery - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm

Comment: What are you trying to determine with this query?

Comment: I'm trying to do this: "Find all students who do not appear in the Likes table (as a student who likes or is liked) and return their names and grades. Sort by grade, then by name within each grade. "

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Please use the subquery:

```
select H.name,H.grade
   from Highschooler H, Likes L
   where H.ID not in (select ID1 from Likes) 
     and H.ID not in (select ID2 from Likes)
   order by H.grade,H.name
```

Comment: Answering a homework question with a raw piece of code is not helpful. Please explain what is wrong with the query in the question.

Comment: @CL. i don't know why. Please help.

Comment: You don't know why answering homework questions with code-only is not loved or why your code is supposed to help?

Comment: @Yunnosch help the code.I don't want to tell why true is true. Everyone see the code will get it. If you want to help,do it.

Comment: I do not understand your request. I am willing to help, but you have to explain with what I should help you. Dou want me to help by explaining your code (which is necessary for a good answer, as for example CL has also already hinted)? Or do you want me to help by explaining why your answer is not as good as it could be? In a comment you tell CL "I don't know why. Please help." You don't know why what? Help with what? Your comment "help the code" I do not understand. It does not seem to have a meaning which I can "parse". To me and my restricted English, it seems to not be an English phrase.

Comment: @Yunnosch there is no need to explain the code.Just a simple sql. We have to write as the rule. Everyone can read it. If you could help to explain the sql.That's very helpful. But I don't see the need. And one question: where are you from? Maybe Japanese? I don' want this to be personal.

Comment: Your answer is a so called code-only answer. This kind of answer supports the impression that StackOverflow is a free coding service, where dumping requirements achieves solutions. (OP, this does not mean you.) Most people at StackOverflow like to think of this as a site for answering questions in order to help people understand, not to do people work for them. This requires explanation. You state that "everybody can read sql". This might be true for people already competent in SQL, if it is medium coplex. It is not true for the target audience of askers at StackOverflow.

Comment: I am not offended by being mistaken for Japanese. But I think some Japanese people might be interested in the reasons for your guess.

Comment: @Yunnosch. Ok. If you want to explain why sql must write as sql. Please go on. I think there is no need. And the sub-query hint is enough for anyone could read sql. Anyway, I don't see the need.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an SQlite db on hand to test but try changing L.ID1 to `L`.ID1.

It seems to be looking for a table named "L.ID1" rather than "L". It's been a while since I've used SQlite though.

Comment: Tried that and got the same error. Also modified my query as follows

select H.name, H.grade from Highschooler H, Likes
where H.ID not in ID1 and H.ID not in ID2
order by H.grade,H.name
;

and I get the same error 'Query failed to execute: no such table: ID1'